# Divergence of $\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{p}(\log x)^{2p}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus

For $p < 1$, why does $$\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{p}(\log x)^{2p}}\, dx$$ diverge?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $x^p(\log x )^{2 p} < x(\log x )$ for $x > e$, $p < 1 $, and minorate the integrand function $\frac{1}{x(\log x )}$, which is divergent.

Comment: Is there any easy way to see that $x^{p}(\log x)^{2p} < x\log x$ for $x > e, 1/2 < p < 1$?

Comment: I might have forgotten that case, somehow...

Comment: The inequality holds *after a while*, we don't need to worry about when exactly. After a while $x^p(\log x)^q\lt x$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that compared with a power of $x$, the function $\log x$ is, for large $x$, so small as to be practically nothing.  Specifically, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$\log x<x^\varepsilon$$
for sufficiently large $x$.  To show that your integral diverges it suffices that
$$x^p(\log x)^{2p}<x\ ,$$
and this is true when
$$\log x<x^{(1-p)/(2p)}\ .$$
If $0<p<1$ then the exponent in the right hand side is positive, and so this inequality is true for sufficiently large $x$.